# Return last item in an Object of arrays via a computed property?

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to create a computed property that will return just the filename in a string (*basically, just returning the last item in an array*)

I have a data object named `attachments` like so:

```
{"abcAttachments":["abc/2019/301902007/acme.pdf","abc/2019/201123007/abc.pdf"],"attachments":["attachments/2019/2da007/hello.png","attachments/2019/2320002007/blue.png"]}
```

What I want to do is return only the filenames from the above Object of arrays, not the entire path of the filenames. For instance, just `acme.pdf` and not `abc/2019/301902007/acme.pdf`

Thus, I tried to do the following computed property:

```
filenames() {
  const files = this.attachments.attachments
  const newArr = files.map(x => x.split('/'))
  return newArr[newArr.length - 1]
}
```

The above code does not just return the last item (it lists all the items). Any tips on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to slightly modify your `map` function:

See JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bwrymeha/

```
var obj = {"abcAttachments":["abc/2019/301902007/acme.pdf","abc/2019/201123007/abc.pdf"],"attachments":["attachments/2019/2da007/hello.png","attachments/2019/2320002007/blue.png"]};

let result = obj.attachments.map((item) => {
    // First split using '/', then return the last item of that split
    // which should be the filename.
    let split = item.split('/');
    return split[split.length - 1];
});

alert(result);
// returns ['hello.png','blue.png']
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for-- thanks! However, I now get a `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` . Do I need to do async.await somewhere?

Comment: well you could just wrap it with `if(obj)` or `if(obj.attachments)`, then the computed property will return `undefined` when your obj is undefined. Or you could prefill your data like `data() { return {obj: {attachments:[]}}}`

Answer (score 0):

If you need just filename from all attachments you need to do the following:

```
filenames() {
    const result = []
    const files = this.attachments
    Object.keys(files).forEach(key => {
        // Here we have "abcAttachments" and "attachments" as "key"
        files[key].map(file => {
            // Split every file by '/'
            const arr = file.split('/')
            if (arr.length) {
                result.push(arr[arr.length - 1])
            }
        })
    })

    return result
}
```

Comment: Thank yoiu for your contribution